# How do I exclude applications from CodeCoverage.exe /IIS analysis

Tags: c#, selenium, iis, jenkins

I have a Jenkins setup on my local machine which runs integration tests using vstest.console.exe. Some of these run Selenium. The vstest.console.exe process gathers coverage analysis to a file and to gather coverage for Selenium tests I use the Team Tools CodeCoverage.exe with the /IIS switch. The build deploys to a local IIS application called IntegrationTests which is the target for the Selenium tests. At the end I merge the coverage generated by vstest.console.exe and the coverage generated by CodeCoverage.exe. It all works very well, until!

Until I debug my web application in Visual Studio. This makes the computer generate some ASP.NET temporary files which is also gathered by CodeCoverage.exe, resulting in duplicates of assemblies in the coverage file generated which makes the results in Jenkins wrong.

So my question is: Does anyone know how to exclude an IIS-application (the one used when debugging) from CodeCoverage.exe analysis? Or to specify that some of the ASP.NET temporary files generated should be exluded?

Thanks,
Drutten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the Modules, Attributes, Sources or Functions to exclude in the RunSettings file?

```
...        
<!-- Match the path of the source files in which each method is defined: -->
        <Sources>
          <Exclude>
            <Source>.*\\atlmfc\\.*</Source>
            <Source>.*\\vctools\\.*</Source>
            <Source>.*\\Service References\\.*</Source>
            <Source>.*\\obj\\.*</Source>
            <Source>.*\\*.designer.cs*</Source>
...
```

And setting the `Settings` flag for [codecoverage.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! Yes I looked at those. I don't use a RunSettings file. However there is a CodeCoverage.config file which has something similar. Maybe i can exclude the IIS application path there. I have the same problem for the integration test IIS application (localhost/IntegrationTests) if I make two runs within a short period of time because then several versions of my assemblies end up in Temporary ASP.NET Files\integrationtests, but I solve that by doing iisreset /stop, delete temp files for integrationtests, iisreset /start. If I wait an hour between runs CodeCoverage.exe includes only recently.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it temporarily by deleting files in temporary asp.net files.